# Vidyo Android SDK and cycle microphone/speaker

Tags: vidyo

When I register a callback for speaker and/or microphone, I can get only 1 device for each, named as "Speaker"(onLocalSpeakerAdded()) and "Micro Phone"(onLocalMicrophoneAdded()) respectively. I also received callbacks for onLocalSpeakerSelected() and onLocalSpeakerStateUpdated() for that identified devices mentioned above. After that, I do not receive any callbacks for onLocalSpeakerAdded() or onLocalMicrophoneAdded() in the event other devices get added.

When I execute the functions below:
vidyoConnector.CycleMicrophone() OR vidyoConnector.CycleSpeaker()
then there is no change in localMicroPhone or localSpeaker selection. Also I was not received callback for "onLocalSpeakerSelected" when calling CycleSpeaker() function.

Another result:
I was connected with Bluetooth headPhone while calling, I was able to hear from that Bluetooth device. Then I disconnected my Bluetooth headphone while still on the call, the call switches to the phone speaker automatically when the Bluetooth headPhone is disconnected but I no callback is invoked.

Query:
- Can you help me on that I am missing?
- Is there any way to find all available devices (i.e.Speaker & microPhone)? 
- Also, can we differentiate between them to identify Bluetooth Speaker, Phone's Loud Speaker or default calling speaker etc.?